# error when using jdbc.app.DB2Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I install db2 expressC 10.5 in an Arch Linux (in virtual machine). Then i try to use COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver to connect to the DB2. All the results are class not found or driver not found. Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class MyJDBC {
    static {
        try { 
            Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            String url = "jdbc:db2:sample";
            if (argv.length == 0) {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
            } else if (argv.length == 2) {
                String userid = argv[0];
                String passwd = argv[1];
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, passwd);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("\nUllU");
            }
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
             ("SELECT EMPNO, LASTNAME " +
              " FROM employee"  +
              " WHERE SALARY > 40000 " );
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("empno = " + rs.getString(1) + " lastname = " + rs.getString(2));
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
       }
    } 
}
```

The environment is:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (ArchLinux build 7.u40_2.4.1-3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)
```

CLASSPATH:

```
   /home/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/function:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/tools/clpplus.jar:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/tools/jline-0.9.93.jar:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:.
```

I think all the drivers(db2java.zip, etc) can be reach, but when i run: `java MyJDBC`, it shows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2:sample
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at MyJDBC.main(MyJDBC.java:19)
```

If specify the classpath:  `java -cp "sqllib/java/*:." MyJDBC`. Firstly, the program throws an exception(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver). Then it shows the right answer. That's unbelievable. Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

PS: I know the new way to connect to DB2 by jcc.DB2Driver, and it works well in my machine. But why the old way cannot work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"why the old way cannot work?"* -- because the type 2 (so called "app") driver was discontinued in DB2 LUW 10.1. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0058719.html